# Angular2 Set focus

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to return focus to the `<button>` which called a custom alert using `ViewChid`.

In my component I have:

```
  @ViewChild('refocus') reFocus: any;

  removeCancel() {
     this.reFocus.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

In my template I added `#refocus` to:

```
<button #refocus class="fbtn2" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="removeDriver(index)">REMOVE</button>
<cp-confirmAlert (confirmCancel)="removeCancel()" (confirmAction)="removeConfirm()"></cp-confirmAlert>
```

My problem is, there can be multiple REMOVE buttons on the page. I have the `index` when clicked but no mater what I try,  the focus gets set to the first one rather than index #2..  Anyone have an idea what I am missing?

Comment: `the focus gets set to the first one rather than index #2.. ` what do mean by this

Comment: There are 2 "REMOVE" buttons.. if I click the second REMOVE link (with Index 1) is sets focus to the first one (with index 0) rather than the same button that was clicked..

Comment: can show from where is the index coming and `cp-confirmAlert ` is what ?

Comment: the code is listed in the original post in the template section..  the template is added to the page multiple times,

Comment: original post ?